# Is it possible to have a NW.js application "not resizeable" but also allow fullscreen?

Tags: nwjs

I'm in a dilemma. I'm adapting an old thing I made for browsers a few years ago into a desktop application with NW.js. I can't make major changes to the code, so this means it's fixed-resolution (not vector-based). A Canvas 2D square of a fixed size.

In my `package.json`, I have therefore set its GUI window to not be resizeable, because if I make it resizeable, the user can resize the window and it looks ugly since the content remains a fixed square.

But with `"resizable": false`, which does prevent the user from resizing the window, it also prevents "fullscreen mode" from working! When I enter fullscreen mode, it does not cover the full screen, but only same size canvas in the top-left part of the screen. This is obviously because I've told it to not be resizeable. If I set `"resizable": true`, the fullscreen works perfectly, but of course the user is then able to resize the window when in non-fullscreen mode!

Is there some way around this? Can the "resizeability" be set dynamically on runtime? I looked for a long time for a solution before asking this.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this manually, here is an example, you'll obviously need to tweak it though.

```html
<button id="enter">Enter Fullscreen</button>
<button id="leave">Leave Fullscreen</button>
<script>
  const enterButton = document.getElementById('enter');
  const leaveButton = document.getElementById('leave');
  const win = nw.Window.get();

  enterButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    win.setResizable(true);
    win.enterFullscreen();
  });
  leaveButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    win.leaveFullscreen();
    win.resizeTo(600, 600);
    win.setResizable(false);
  });
</script>
```